# How can we get the complete list of class names from which it has been inherited in python

Tags: python, inspect

I am able to get the members in a class file from the inspect methods in python but now I also need to fetch the complete list of the class tree, for e.g. from which it has been inherited. So how can this be done. I am trying it using this method but it throws error

the code is as follows

```
for name in inspect.getclasstree(a.Simpleclass):
    print "classes is " + name
```

please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`inspect.getmro()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro) should be what you need.

```
>>> class A: pass
>>> class B: pass
>>> class C(A, B): pass
>>> [c.__name__ for c in inspect.getmro(C)]
['C', 'A', 'B']
```

Comment: In theis it prints the address so how can we print only the class names